# calling bringChildToFront() from a surfaceView within a frameLayout doesn't work?

Tags: android, parent-child, surfaceview, android-framelayout

Can you add a surfaceView child to a frameLayout, and then call bringChildToFront() to bring another child view in front of the surfaceView?

This is my first android app I've made, so please let me know if my setup makes any sense or if i'm doing the wrong things in the wrong places.

- I have one activity, which has a FrameLayout.
- I have 2 views (named pauseMenuView and mainMenuView) that are simply Views that have 4 buttons.  These menu buttons are handled by overriding onClick() inside my activity.
- I have a 3rd custom view (called gameView) that extends SurfaceView.  This is where I am currently processing almost everything about my gameplay (handling touch events, drawing graphics, animation, collision detection). I have a seperate thread for controlling the state (paused, unpaused, etc.) and framerate of the game.

So basically, while playing the game, I have a pause icon in the top left corner of the screen.  I'm trying to make it so that when they touch that icon, my gameView's onTouchEvent calls bringChildToFront(pauseMenuView) to display the pause menu.  However, currently when I call bringChildToFront() or bringToFront(), nothing happens as if they have no effect.  My gameView is still visible.

Here's the relevant code from my activity:

```
public static final int INDEX_MAIN_MENU_VIEW = 0;
public static final int INDEX_PAUSE_MENU_VIEW = 1;
public static final int INDEX_GAMEVIEW_VIEW = 2;

fl = new FrameLayout(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
fl.setLayoutParams(lp);

mainMenuView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.main_menu,null);
pauseMenuView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.pause_menu, null);

fl.addView(mainMenuView, INDEX_MAIN_MENU_VIEW);
fl.addView(pauseMenuView, INDEX_PAUSE_MENU_VIEW);

setContentView(fl);

View onePlayerButton = findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_button);        
onePlayerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
/* then i set up a bunch of pauseMenu and mainMenu buttons the same way, so I won't put them here */

fl.bringChildToFront(mainMenuView);
```

So when the app starts, the mainMenuView is brought to the front, and when the player clicks the onePlayerButton, a gameView gets created and added to the frameLayout, brought to the front, and the user starts playing the game.

```
    gv = new GameView(this, 1);
    fl.addView(fv, INDEX_GAMEVIEW_VIEW);
    fl.bringChildToFront(gv);
    fl.invalidate();
```

Then, when in game, when the user clicks the pause icon in my gameView, the onTouchEvent() method catches it and I do this. (I just made my pauseMenuView public so my gameView could see it)...It seems like my program goes straight to the mThread.pause() line and doesn't do anything with the first 2 lines... I've tried setting the gameView to invisible here, and when I do that, the screen is completely black, but I can click where the pause buttons WOULD be if the pause menu was visible, and they actually do get detected by my activity's onClick()! What is going on here?

```
    ((TestGame)getContext()).fl.bringChildToFront(((TestGame)getContext()).pauseMenuView);
    ((TestGame)getContext()).pauseMenuView.bringToFront();
    mThread.pause();
```

Comment: so I solved my bug, after 2 days of searching.  It turns out that the key was to set the background color of my gameView to Color.Transparent, and boom, everything works... I had no idea that setting was so critical.  Hopefully anyone else who runs into this problem finds this solution faster than I did, haha.

Comment: Your answer isnt clear, What if i need my background color to be yellow and not transparent ?

Comment: Thanks Neil you saved me.  I had a similar problem with a ImageButton overlaid on a Custom SurfaceView.  If I did .setRotation(float) on the view, it would not be visible on screen (even though it should have been due to the view hierarchy), but would still respond to touch events.  It's very strange that setting the background color on the SurfaceView fixed my problem.